# Dividing a set of numbers in to two sets such that sum of elements in each set must be equal

Tags: java, arrays, testing, puzzle

i have made a java program for following problem statement -

"Dividing    a set of numbers in to two sets such that sum of elements in each set    must be equal "

input: array of integers

output:

"Yes"-if set can be    divided in to two equal sum,

"No" -if can not be divided in to two    equal sum,

"Invalid" -if integer array contains any other type of Integers(excepting positive integers)

and i have submitted the code to an online compiler and the code i have    written has passed 8 test cases out of 10.i tried hard but i couldnt    succeed finding those two test cases which failed . what are those two test-cases which failed ? here's the code -

```
public class CandidateCode {

    public static String partition(int[] arr) {
        int sum = getSum(arr);
        int half = sum / 2;
        int out = 0;
        int i = 0;

        boolean flag = false;
        if (hasZero(arr)) {
            return "Invalid";
        }
        if (sum % 2 != 0) {
            return "No";
        }
        if (arr.length == 2) {
            if (arr[0] == arr[1]) {
                return "Yes";
            }
            return "No";
        }

        else {

            while (i < arr.length) {
                if (arr[i] < half)
                    out += arr[i];
                if (out == half) {
                    flag = true;
                    break;
                }
                i++;
            }

        }
        if (flag)
            return "Yes";
        else
            return "No";
    }

    public static int getSum(int[] arr) {
        int result = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            result += arr[i];
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static boolean hasZero(int[] arr) {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i] <= 0) {
                return true;
            }

        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Post this on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Secondly - format your code.

Answer (score 0):

One test case that would fail is an array consisting of:

4 8 4

Comment: no this test case does not fail , i have checked it , it returns "Yes" which is what is expected. @Sbodd

Comment: Can you clarify your requirements then?  I assumed based on your code that the array had to be partitioned - e.g. all elements from 0 to N had to sum to half.

Comment: If an arbitrary partition is allowed, then I think 2 2 6 4 2 would fail your test.

Comment: "Dividing a set of numbers in to two sets such that sum of elements in each set must be equal "

input: array of integers

output:

"Yes"-if set can be divided in to two equal sum,

"No" -if can not be divided in to two equal sum,

"Invalid" -if integer array contains any other type of Integers(excepting positive integers)  , this is all required .